# Unity3D UI button need multiple click to play or pause audio

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

Why does my play or pause button need multiple clicks to play or pause the audio? If the target is detected it will display a UI button and if clicked it will play a sound and when clicked again it will pause but I need multiple click to trigger the code.
any solutions? this is my code.

```c#
void playSound(string ss)
{
    clipTarget = (AudioClip)Resources.Load(ss);
    soundTarget.clip = clipTarget;
    soundTarget.loop = false;
    soundTarget.playOnAwake = false;
    soundTarget.ignoreListenerPause = true;
}
```

```c#
if (name == "quezon")
{       
    if (Translate.GetComponent<Text>().text == "ENGLISH")
    {
        Narrator.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        myGirl.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        myBoy.enabled = false;
        ButtonAction.GetComponent<Button().onClick.AddListener(delegate {
            if (soundTarget.isPlaying)
            {
                soundTarget.Pause();
                btn.image.overrideSprite = Play;
                myBoy.enabled = false;
            }
            else if(!soundTarget.isPlaying)
            {
                soundTarget.Play();
                playSound("sounds/English");
                btn.image.overrideSprite = Pause;
                myBoy.enabled = true;
            }
        });
        TextDescription.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Manuel L. Quezon was born on August 19, 1878, and died on August 1, 1944. "
            + "He was a Filipino statesman, soldier, and politician who served as president of the Commonwealth of the " 
            + "Philippines from 1935 to 1944.";
        TextTargetName.GetComponent<Text>().text = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the button onClick behaviour only once. Like this:

```
void Awake ()
{
    ButtonAction.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener (() => ToggleSound ());
}

private void ToggleSound ()
{
    if (soundTarget.isPlaying)
    {
        soundTarget.Pause();
        btn.image.overrideSprite = Play;
        myBoy.enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        soundTarget.Play();
        playSound("sounds/English");
        btn.image.overrideSprite = Pause;
        myBoy.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

What I think is happening is since you are adding listeners everytime that routine happens it triggers first once, then twice, then thrice and so on.

Thats is the syntax I commonly use for adding behaviour to UI buttons, is easy, you can add parameters and looks clean. I recommend it.

Also if you dont have parameters you can do this and its easier.

```
ButtonAction.GetComponent<Button().onClick.AddListener (ToggleSound);
```